# Solr index Multiple Rows into one

Tags: sql, solr

Imagine I'm getting this four rows from a Query:

> ID: 1 | NAME: TOY | TYPE: 1
>   ID: 1 | NAME: TOY | TYPE: 2
>   ID: 1 | NAME: TOY | TYPE: 3
>   ID: 1 | NAME: TOY | TYPE: 4

Without making a query that concatenate this into a single row, is it possible to use Solr multiValued option to index this to like

> ID: 1 | NAME: TOY | TYPE:{1,2,3,4}

Comment: Which database are you querying? MySQL has `GROUP_CONCAT` that allows you to get these as a single column value, and then you can split the content in Solr into a multivalued field again.

Comment: I'm using oracle, the problem is that i want to avoid concatenate functions because there will always be a limitation on length of that field